# Remove users reaction when they have clicked on the ReactionCollector

Tags: discord.js

I have a ReactionCollector and as soon as I click on the right arrow reaction, I want it to remove my reaction instantly; so I can react again as soon as possible. How do I go about this? Here's my code boss.

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed().setDescription(`test`);
    const listEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
    await listEmbed.react("➡️")

    const filter = (reaction, user) => ["➡️"].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && (message.member.id == user.id)
    const collector = listEmbed.createReactionCollector(filter)

    collector.on("collect", async (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === "➡️") {

    //remove user reaction

 }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure it's:

```
reaction.users.remove(message.author.id)
```

You have the `reaction`, you take the `users`, and remove the reaction from `message.author.id`.